# Java Automatic Value

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for(int limit1=1; limit1<=1; limit1++){
System.out.print("Number of criteria (Max: 5): ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
System.out.println();
if (n>5 || n<1){
    System.out.println("Sorry the maximum limit is 5");
    System.out.println("Please try again");
    System.out.println();
    limit1=limit1-1;
    continue;
}
double[] arrayCrit = new double[n];
double[] arrayPerc= new double[n];
String[] arrayCritName = new String[n];
double percentage=0, check=0, cent=0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  System.out.print("Criteria("+(i+1)+"): ");
  arrayCritName[i] = inpt.readLine();
for(int limit2=1; limit2<=1; limit2++){
    if(n==1){
        arrayCrit[i] = 100/100;
        System.out.print("Percentage: 100%");
        break;
      }
  System.out.print("Percentage: ");
  arrayCrit[i] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine()); 
      if(arrayCrit[i]>100 || arrayCrit[i]<1){
        System.out.println("Sorry, minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 100");
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        System.out.println();
        limit2=limit2-1;            
      }
        check=check+arrayCrit[i];   

     if(check>100 || check<1){
        System.out.println("User didn't meet the default percentage (100%)");
        System.out.println(check);
        check=check-arrayCrit[i];
        limit2=limit2-1;
        continue;   
}
 arrayCrit[i] = arrayCrit[i]/100;

}

}
```

Hello, I need help when inputting the percentage. I would like to know if it's possible for the last input to automatically put the value.

for example:

- Number of Criteria: 3
- Criteria(1) - Attendance
- Percentage: 25
- Criteria(2) - Quiz
- Percentage - 25
- Criteria(3) - Exam
- Percentage - 50 <--- Automatically will be there, no need to input.

Thanks!

Comment: `for(int limit1=1; limit1<=1; limit1++)` really ?

Comment: He is using that `for` to implement a retry system. In my opinion it would be best to use a simple `while` or a `do while`, but his code would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned and fixed your code a bit:

-I changed your retry `for`s for `while`s.

-I deleted some unused variables.

-I solved your automatic value problem. I understand that you want that automatic value to be 100 minus the sum of all the previous percentages the user has entered. Since you are saving the `check` variable you just haev to print (100-check) when you reach the last execution (n-1).

This is the code:

```
System.out.print("Number of criteria (Max: 5): ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
System.out.println();
while( n>5 || n<1 ){
    System.out.println("Sorry the maximum limit is 5");
    System.out.println("Please try again");
    System.out.println();

    n = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
}

double[] arrayCrit = new double[n];
String[] arrayCritName = new String[n];
double check=0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    System.out.print("Criteria("+(i+1)+"): ");
    arrayCritName[i] = inpt.readLine();

    if(i == n-1){
        arrayCrit[i] = (100-check)/100;
        System.out.print("Percentage: "+(100-check)+"%");
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print("Percentage: ");

    while(true){
        arrayCrit[i] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine()); 

        if(arrayCrit[i]>100 || arrayCrit[i]<1){
            System.out.println("Sorry, minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 100");
            System.out.println("Please try again");
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        } 

        check=check+arrayCrit[i];  

        if(check>100 || check<1){
            System.out.println("User didn't meet the default percentage (100%)");
            System.out.println(check);
            check=check-arrayCrit[i];
            continue;   
        }

        arrayCrit[i] = arrayCrit[i]/100;
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, thanks. But somehow I'm getting an error where I input criteria 2: percentage: 25, then it will just continue to let me input.. the criteria name is not moving.

Comment: Have you added the `break` at the end of my code? I edited my post and added it a couple minutes after posting it.

Comment: Wow! You're a life saver. I've been wondering how to do this for about 3 days now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Change the piece of code where you are printing the string Percentage and reading it.It should be like this...

```
if(i != n-1)
{
   System.out.print("Percentage: ");
   arrayCrit[i] = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine()); 
   if(arrayCrit[i]>100 || arrayCrit[i]<1){
    System.out.println("Sorry, minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 100");
    System.out.println("Please try again");
    System.out.println();
    limit2=limit2-1;            
  }
}
else
{
   System.out.print("Percentage: 50");
}
```

instead of 50 put what ever value/variable that holds the value.

Comment: Is it possible for the other inputted value, like for example
2 or 4?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you have that value stored in a variable. Say if your variable name is val. System.out.print("Percentage: " + val); will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to say "Percentage [default: 50]" instead of "Percentage" and use some processing logic to find whether the user has actually typed a different number.

A more advanced solution is to use some line editing library like GNU readline in C. For Java, there is [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/).